# Firebase and RxJS

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I made a function that listens to value events:

```
getUnreadMessages() : Observable<any>{
    return new Observable(observer =>{
      firebase.database().ref('messages/' + this.userService.getUserID()).on("value", (snapshot : any) =>{

        let count = 0;
        ...some more logic here...

        observer.next(count);
        observer.complete();

      }, (error) =>{
        observer.error(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

When the database changes, I can see that this function is entered, yet where I subscribe to it throughout the application doesn't fire. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but why are you marking the observable complete after the first value?

Comment: I thought that was to handle propagation per value.

Comment: does it enter the callback?

Comment: No, it does not, not the subscription callback

Comment: I am not quite sure why this is not working for, but I am also not quite sure why you are not using AngularFire, which already has done the work of wrapping Firebase Database in observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking the observable complete was the cause of the problem.